# SBT generates a $global directory that suspends sbt assembly

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

We're using SBT 0.13.13 with SBT assembly 0.14.3

Lately, `sbt assembly` started getting stuck when trying to read some XML files. After some digging we found out it happens because SBT generates a directory streams under the target dir & inside that streams dir it generates a directory $global. I'm not quite sure whats this $global dir is but if I cd into, it takes me back to my root dir

We were only able to actually execute the `sbt assembly` successfully after adding this to our assembly merge strategy code:

```
case ff if !ff.getAbsolutePath.contains("$") =>
          XML.loadFile(ff)
```

And so my questions are:

- Why is SBT generating a streams dir under target?
- What is this mysterious $global dir?
- Did someone else encounter this issue and solved it in a more elegant way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: SBT 0.13.8 is quite old. Did you try upgrading your SBT? Latest version is `0.13.15`.

Comment: Hi Yuval, I had a mistake in the version, we're actually using 0.13.13

Comment: I see. Try using `logLevel in assembly := Level.Debug`, you might get more information about where it's actually stuck, perhaps that can help us narrow down the problem.

Comment: I know where the problem is - its trying to read the $global dir under target/streams and it fails. Once I tell it to ignore dirs containing $ its working. I'm curious to understand what is actually happening here

Comment: I don't know if it is related, but this sbt issue causing an IOException because of the $global dir has been dogging us for...years. https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2156

Comment: I also want to know this mysterious $global dir, anyone knows? THanks